# Allow only uploading files to SharePoint online programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We're using a SharePoint online site as a backend repository for a web application. The web application has a UI to allow users to upload/download/view files using Graph API. That means the web application is registered as an Azure web application and is using users' delegated permission, so when a user uploads a file, we can see his/her username on the file at the SharePoint site.

Is there some way to disable users directly uploading files when they visit the SharePoint site and only allow the web site programmatically upload files on behalf of the user?

Answer (score 0):

Using users' delegated permission means that you have implemented behalf of the user flow.

What you need currently is to disable users directly uploading files in SharePoint online site.

You have two options:

Hide the "Upload" button through CSS. But this method just hides an entry on the sharepoint website. In fact, users can still save a document directly from an Office Application to the Sharepoint library. I will not elaborate on it here.

The second method is to provide the user/group View Only Permission Level. You can see [this post on StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225077/disable-new-document-in-document-library-for-specific-users/225080#225080) for details about how to restrict users to upload or add a new document by managing unique permission for your library.